# Javascript selecting constructor dynamically, is this incorrect?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, new-operator

I'm trying to dynamically create objects based on a declared type. This code seems to work but I feel like I may be setting myself up for a spectacular failure further down the line.

I suppose the question is - is this good code and if not, why not?

```
//TypeA and TypeB are constuctor functions declared elsewhere which take data objects, omitted here for clarity.
var constructorMapping = { 'typeA': TypeA, 'typeB': TypeB };

function convertToObject( type, dataObject) {
    var selectedConstructor = constructorMapping[type];
        if ( !selectedConstructor ) {
            return false;
        }
        return new selectedConstructor(dataObject);
}

var typeAObject = convertToObject("typeA", {name: "asdf"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine, assuming that all your `TypeA`/`TypeB`/… constructors take such `dataObject`s as their argument.

However, I wouldn't return `false`. Either throw an error, or return `null`. Also, you only check that `selectedConstructor` is truthy, you could make that check more strict if you want:

```
function convertToObject(type, dataObject) {
    if (!constructorMapping.hasOwnProperty(type)) return null;
    var selectedConstructor = constructorMapping[type];
    if (typeof selectedConstructor != "function") return null;
    return new selectedConstructor(dataObject);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback. I'm still struggling with how to deal with errors in javascript without breaking functionality, mostly I just try to avoid the typeerrors being thrown in console.